# Is the set is open, closed in the space $C[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Determine whether the set is open, closed in the space $C[0,1]$:
$$A=\left\{x(t) \in C[0,1]: e^t \leqslant x(t)<12\right\}$$
My book contains only definitions, and while I grasp the concepts, I'm struggling to apply them to real problems. I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to MSE. Could you write a little more about what your thoughts are about this problem? Do you think it will be open and/or closed? What have you attempted so far? I will give a small hint - do you know if the set $\{x \in \Bbb R : 0 \le x < 12\}$ is open/closed?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, An open set is a set where every element, together with some neighborhood, is contained within the set. I assume that if the inequality were strict (> 0) instead of non-strict (≥ 0), then it would be an open set (we can always take a neighborhood). And because it's non-strict (≥ 0), does it then become a closed set?

Comment: The answer to my hint-question is that $\{x \in \Bbb R : 0 \le x < 12\}$ is neither open nor closed. This is because no neighbourhood of $0$ is a contained in the set, but also no neighbourhood of $12$ is contained in the complement. If that wasn't obvious to you, it might be worth trying to find some exercises on the topology of $\Bbb R$! I think it helps a lot to have some experience with the topology of a fairly "visualisable" space like $\Bbb R$.